# Xamarin Android VS - Crash on 8.0 Phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, crash

There is a weird crash ever since I started tests on my app with android oreo OS.

Over some time(a day sometimes, others takes 2-3 days) the foreground service will crash/stop without any notice. From the debug I've got, it says `android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable`, but I'm not sure who is the actual culprit.
The weird thing is also that it crashes after its been started, but the function that says is the reason of crash should be called just once while the service is started(OnStartCommand).

From what I've seen, the culprit is the OnStartCommand, or so the error says, but im not entirely sure what the actual problem is and how to fix it.
Removing all the new code thats been added since starting work with 8.0 Oreo did not yield any result.

Has anyone else had this problem and is there a solution to it?

Code:

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            isStarted = true;

            LoadSet();//load settings
            accumulatedTrafficDown += intent.GetLongExtra("aDownBootup", 0);
            accumulatedTrafficUp += intent.GetLongExtra("aUpBootup", 0);

            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)(Application.Context.GetSystemService(ConnectivityService));
            wifiManager = (WifiManager)(Application.Context.GetSystemService(WifiService));
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

            builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ITMIcon)
                .SetOngoing(true)//API 11
                .SetShowWhen(false)//API 17
                .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public)
                ;

            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 26)
            {
                string chanName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_normal);
                var importance = NotificationImportance.Low;

                NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(DEF_CHANNEL, chanName, importance)
                {
                    LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
                };
                chan.EnableLights(false);
                chan.EnableVibration(false);
                chan.SetShowBadge(false);
                chan.SetBypassDnd(true);

                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
                builder.SetChannelId(DEF_CHANNEL);

                chan.Dispose();
            }

            //open main app when notification is clicked
            using (Intent intentMA = new Intent(this/*Application.ApplicationContext*/, typeof(MainActivity)))
            {
                intentMA.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReceiverForeground);

                using (PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intentMA, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent))
                {
                    builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                }
            }

            StartForeground(notificationId/*(int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService*/, builder.Build());

            lastNetworkTrafficDown = TrafficStats.TotalRxBytes;
            lastNetworkTrafficUp = TrafficStats.TotalTxBytes;

            //for drawing to tray
            bm = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmapSize, bitmapSize, Bitmap.Config.Argb4444, true);
            canvas = new Canvas(bm);
            bounds = new Rect();
            paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.LinearText) { Color = Color.White };
            paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
            paint.SetShadowLayer(4f, 2f, 2f, Color.Black);//(int)(bitmapSize * 0.03125f), (int)(bitmapSize * 0.015625f), (int)(bitmapSize * 0.015625f)
            paint.TextAlign = Paint.Align.Center;
            using (Typeface bold = Typeface.Create(paint.Typeface, TypefaceStyle.Bold))
            {
                paint.SetTypeface(bold);
            }

            UpdateNotification();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
```

Error:

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at ITM.NotificationService.OnStartCommand (Android.Content.Intent intent, Android.App.StartCommandFlags flags, System.Int32 startId) [0x00016] in <8eb370332be94963ab6dd55bf21270bf>:0
at Android.App.Service.n_OnStartCommand_Landroid_content_Intent_II (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_intent, System.Int32 native_flags, System.Int32 startId) [0x0000f] in <5714ccdc0ab84d74bb3e08064f494a0a>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.f8a85e62-c1d3-4a9f-baf4-1379f6e1f4f1(intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int)
  at com.nevaran.ITMNotificationService.n_onStartCommand (Native Method)
  at com.nevaran.ITMNotificationService.onStartCommand (ITMNotificationService.java:31)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1801)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```